# Reading images from HDFS

Tags: java, image-processing, hdfs, hadoop2

I have about 150K images stored in HDFS. Their metadata(timestamp, path) are stored in HBase table. I have a method:

> addImage(timestamp, File)

which  upload images to some remote server. I tried the following code to read images from local filesystem:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp/vehicle_frames.jpg"));
System.out.println("Width of image: " + image.getWidth());
```

The 'image' variable contains actual image that I can pass to addImage() method.

As in case of HDFS how can I read image and store in a variable for further processing.

Please share some helpful link or suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried? As ImageIO can read from InputStream instances, and org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem can create them I don't understand your question?

Comment: I can read the image from local file system using ImageIO.read() but how can I do same reading operation while my images stored in HDFS?

Comment: Have you tried to use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem to create an InputStream which reads your image from HDFS?

Comment: Thanks to pointing me out towards  org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem. I will try and update soon!